# Why can't I cd into this directory?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, cd

I'm trying to cd into a directory, but the terminal says it doesn't exist even though it does.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `cd` with two arguments, `Prog` and `16.1`. You need to call it with just one argument, `Prog 16.1`. To do this, you need to "quote" the space in the middle, so that it doesn't get interpreted as separating two arguments. Here are a few options:

> - `cd 'Prog 16.1'`
> - `cd Prog' '16.1`
> - `cd "Prog 16.1"`
> - `cd Prog" "16.1`
> - `cd Prog\ 16.1`

Comment: oh man, rookie mistake, but is guess that's what I get for putting spaces in my filenames

Comment: Depending on your shell, filename completion will probably help here. Type `cd Prog` and then TAB; it will be expanded to something like `cd Prog\ 16.1/`

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's often true, but not in the OP's case, since the same directory contains (for example) a file named `Program 10.3`. (Some shells will still *try* to help, but none would be very successful in the OP's case. And the OP is using Bash, which won't even try.)

Comment: Good point -- but bash *does* do that kind of auto-completion, at least if you configure it properly (I tested it with bash before posting the comment).

Comment: @KeithThompson: To make perfectly sure I'm understanding you -- in my experience Bash will only autocomplete a filename if you've typed an unambiguous prefix (so in the OP's directory, `Program\ 10` would autocomplete to `Program\ 10.3`), though it can also extend an ambiguous prefix up to the first point of ambiguity (so in the OP's directory, `Progr` would autocomplete up to `Program\ `). Are you saying that Bash can be configured to attempt autocompletion even *past* that point (like how Zsh does, or like how the Command Prompt does in Windows)?

Comment: No, you're right, it only autocompletes unambiguously. Hitting TAB again shows a list of matching names, but you still have to start typing one of them, and in this case you'd have to escape the space somehow. As the OP suggests, it's a good reason to avoid space in file names.

Answer (score -2):

The command replies with an accurate message, all one needs to do is read the error message.